# Casting Character to char and char to Character Java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

Can somebody please explain me why this code is working fine?

```
import java.io.*;

public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        FileOutputStream fo=new FileOutputStream("Character.dat");
        ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(fo);
        FileInputStream fi=new FileInputStream("Character.dat");
        ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(fi);
        Character c = 'h';
        oos.writeObject(c);
        Character arr = (char)ois.readObject();
        System.out.println(arr);
        fo.close();
        fi.close();
        oos.close();
        ois.close();
    }
}
```

In Line 10, I have created a `Character` and I have serialized it in line 11 and written into a file.
In line 12, I have deserialized that object, it returns a reference of `Object`, thus we have to downcast it into `Character`. In line 12, I am downcasting it into char (which is a primitive data type and not a class) and still its working fine. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

I think your cast from an object to a char and then assignment to a Character is still working because of Java's autoboxing going on behind the scenes. This [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) might help explain it more in depth.

Answer (score 1):

Java uses a technique called [Autoboxing and -unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). This provides build-in casts from primitives to their hull-classes and back. That is the reason why you can write `Character c = 'h'` instead of `Character c = new Character('h');` in the first place.

You may want to use this technique with care since [it can have a heavy impact to performance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/autoboxing.html).